# What can I delete after moving MySQL database files location

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to move the location of database files from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/home/lib/mysql`

I only changing database files. Socket is still `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` (only changing `datadir` in `my.cnf`)

Now, all data in `/var/lib/mysql` has been copied to `/home/lib/mysql`

MySQL has been started and everything is fine. Now time to cleaning up data in `/var/lib/mysql`

but I'm not sure what data can and cannot be removed in `/var/lib/mysql`

this is data (except database name) in `/var/lib/mysql`:

```
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
mysql
```

Comment: One thing you can do is let mysql run for a bit... if it's still writing to those files for something, their modification times will be updated.  You might be able to use access times to determine if mysql is reading from the file, but if you have a backup process or anything else accessing those files it will be less helpful.

Answer (score 4):

After successfully moving your data dir, you can just delete the whole folder and its files/subfolder.

```
$sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

You just need to double-check you have all the data.

Comment: I agree. I usually just move the directory instead of copying its content.

Comment: I did that and now: `sudo mysqld --initialize
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` big sigh...

Comment: fixed it by deleting `/etc/mysql` + deluser mysql + apt-get remove/purge & reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1

is related with the inoddb engine used by mysql to store data.

look into /etc/my.cnf (or where ever is my.cnf) to see where is configured inoddb to put hist data.

look for some things like

```
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/ibdata
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1500M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/iblog
innodb_log_arch_dir = /var/lib/mysql/iblog
```

once you have all set into my.cnf you can restart mysql to take effect.
also right now you can look into the new location if inoddb makes data and log files and into the old location if updates the files.

don't delete those files unless you are done with the migration.